# Azure AD does not sync attributes of an extended schema using SCIM 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b, scim2

I have an application that exposes two SCIM 2.0 schemes to sync users:

"id": *"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"*,

"id": *"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:bizagi:2.0:UserProperties"*

I'm trying to sync users with Azure AD, with default schema *"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"* no problem, but with extended schema *"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:bizagi:2.0:UserProperties"* attributes do not reach my application.

I also tried to extend the schema *"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"* to sync my extended attributes but it didn't work either.

The definition of my extended schema was made following the indications of this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-3.2) and I exposed it in the endpoint /scim/v2/Schemas. The definition looks like this:

```
{
    "totalResults": 2,
    "itemsPerPage": 10,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
    ],
    "Resources": [
        {
            "id": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
            "name": "User",
            "description": "User Account",
            "attributes": [ ... ]               
        },
        {
            "id": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:bizagi:2.0:UserProperties",
            "name": "...",
            "description": "...",
            "attributes": [             
                {
                    "name": "PropertyString",
                    "type": "string",
                    "multiValued": false,
                    "description": "PropertyString",
                    "required": false,
                    "caseExact": false,
                    "mutability": "readWrite",
                    "returned": "default",
                    "uniqueness": "none"
                },
                {
                    "name": "IdentificationNumber",
                    "type": "string",
                    "multiValued": false,
                    "description": "Identification Number",
                    "required": false,
                    "caseExact": false,
                    "mutability": "readWrite",
                    "returned": "default",
                    "uniqueness": "none"
                },
                ...
```

In Azure AD, from the advanced Attribute Mapping option I added my extended attributes to the list of attributes as shown in the following image:

[Edit Attribute List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeZ5O.png)

Then I did the mapping of the extended attribute but it doesn't sync.

[Attribute Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oKtT.png)

In my application the user can create custom user properties and it is not possible to use the default attributes offered by SCIM.

**Does anyone know how I can sync these extended attributes in my app from Azure AD?**

Or

**if I am doing something wrong?**